c# - Getting client certificate in Azure Function local development
I'm developing an Azure function app. This app will require the caller to supply a client certificate as part of the http call. Then I wish to get the sent client certificate and validate it against some logic to tell if the user has access to the needed resource or not.
I followed the instructions here:
https://damienbod.com/2020/09/04/securing-azure-functions-using-certificate-authentication/
I understand that X-ARR-ClientCert is only valid in Azure environment, and for development environment I tried getting the certificate though req.HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate where req is the HttpRequest and it doesn't return it.
How can I get the client certificate in development mode (using Visual Studio)?

maybe check this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/718852/function-apps-should-have-client-certificates-(inc

Thanks. It's the same code as in the URL I have pasted. I'm looking at getting the client certificate on development machine (while debugging) so I can develop my logic.

Check if this article helps, @developer82.
